# SSRS Report Auto Generating

Tags: reporting-services

My report in SSRS currently auto generates when I open the report, but I want it to only run when parameters are entered and the user clicks to View Report. I tried setting up a hidden parameter with the default values and available values set to none. When I do this and preview the report I get an error that "The _____ parameter is missing a value." I tried to allow allow null values but when I do that it auto generates the report so I'm back to square one. What's the best way to go about solving this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want the user to choose parameters.. why are you providing default values? Doesn't make sense!

Comment: Just set at least one parameter without a default. Note that if you have deployed the report already, the deployed version's default will not get overwritten. You can change the defaults via the web portal or simply remove and redeploy the report.